# HTML form shows "cannot POST / " when I try to submit

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, input

I looked over some similar questions, but none of them worked.

I'm working on a back-end development project for Free Code Camp https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/back-end-development-and-apis/back-end-development-and-apis-projects/exercise-tracker

and I cannot get the form to post. When submitted shows "cannot POST /"

Here is the simplified HTML form

```
   <form id="exercise-form" action="" method="post">
          <div>
            <input id="uid" name=":_id" >
          </div>

         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>

 <script>
    const exerciseForm = document.getElementById("exercise-form");

    exerciseForm.addEventListener("submit", () => {

      const userId = document.getElementById("uid").value;
     
      exerciseForm.action = `/api/users/${userId}/exercises`;

      // I've tried this as well
      // exerciseForm.setAttribute('action', `/api/users/${userId}/exercises`);

      exerciseForm.submit();
    });
  </script>
```

here is app.js, I've tried replacing get method with post, still not working

Also, should I get the id from req.body._id or req.params._id ?

```
app.get('/api/users/:_id/exercises', (req, res, next) => {
    
let inputId = req.params._id


    res.json({
        _id: inputId,   
    })
})
```

Here is repl with app.js and index.html if needed https://replit.com/join/qjeykaiqxp-abror

Later, I need to display database results for that id.

Comment: Don't write `next()` after `res.json` in your `app.js`. `res.json` already produces a response, so you must not delegate that task to the "next" handler. And take the ID from `req.params._id`.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the next() handler, but still cannot figure out why form shows cannot POST /

Comment: Also, write `app.post('/api/users/:_id/exercises', ...)`, not `app.get(...)`. But that still does not explain why your browser makes at `POST /` request.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried with both post() and get(), still not working. I forgot to include it in the description

Comment: Can you share the _full_ HTML form (you shared only a _simplified_ version)?

Comment: event.preventDefault()

Comment: Here is the repl with app.js and index.html. Please have a look  https://replit.com/join/qjeykaiqxp-abror

Comment: Can't open that link.

Comment: Can you try the link in the description, please